# Batch file - VBScript runtime error: Path not found

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, unzip

My Batch script is complaining that it can not find the path (not sure what path as its not too precise with explaining what is that its having problems with. The error message i get is:

```
C:/Users/Boss/AppData/Local/Temp/_.vbs(3, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Path not found
```

The whole idea of this script is to donwload tomcat (and not only) place it in specified directory, unzip and set it up. Now for some reason the UnZip method works perfectly fine for downloading and unziping Ant, but for Tomcat it does not. Below is the installAnt and installTomcat methods and UnZip method.

```
:installAnt 
    ::----- ANT Section -----::

    :: Setup Apache Ant if Ant does not exist
    md "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7\" 2>nul

    :: Set filename variable
    SET "FILENAME=%~dp0\apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"

    :: Download ANT from mirror
    bitsadmin.exe /transfer "Apache Ant Download" http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.apache.org//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip "%FILENAME%"

    :: Copy Apache Ant to C:\Apache
    xcopy "%~dp0apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"  "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\."

    :: Delete zip file from curent directory
    del "%~dp0apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"

    :: Unzip Apache Ant to C:\Apache
    call :UnZipFile "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\" "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"

    :: Delete zip folder
    del "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"

    :: Set ANT_HOME path
    set "ANT_HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7"
    setx ANT_HOME "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7" /m

    :: Add ANT to path
    set "path=%PATH%;%ant_home%\bin"
    setx path "%PATH%" /m

    goto checkIvy

:installTomcat
    ::----- Tomcat Section -----::
    echo Installing tomcat
    :: Setup Apache Tomcat if Tomcat does not exist
    md "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\" 2>nul

    :: Set filename variable
    SET "FILENAME=%~dp0\apache-tomcat-7.0.56.zip"

    :: Download Tomcat from mirror
    bitsadmin.exe /transfer "Apache Tomcat Donwload" http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.56/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.56.zip "%FILENAME%"


    :: Copy Apache Tomcat to C:\Apache
    xcopy "%~dp0apache-tomcat-7.0.56.zip" "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\."

    :: Delete zip file from curent direcotry
    del "%~dp0apache-tomcat-7.0.56.zip"

    :: Unzip Apache Tomcat to C:\Apache
    call :UnZipFile "%HOMEDRIVE\Apache\" "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.56.zip"

    pause

    rem :: Delete zip folder
    rem del "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.56.zip"

    rem :: Set TOMCAT_HOME
    rem set "TOMCAT_HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.56"
    rem setx TOMCAT_HOME "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.56" /m

    rem :: Add TOMCAT to path
    rem set "path=%PaTH%;%tomcat_home%\bin"
    rem setx path "%PATH%" /m
```

Unzip function:

```
:: Unzip file
:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
goto :eof
```

Unfortunately i am not an expert with Batch files and i am having troubles figuring out why it works for Ant but not for Tomcat method.

Line 3 of that batch file:

```
:: @Author:  Maciej Cygan
```

Comment: The error is from the generated VBScript, not from the batch file. What does line 3 of that file look like?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Its just a comment really as per update

Comment: Line 3 of the generated VBScript, **NOT** the batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your:

```
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
```

and this evidence:

```
>> p = "N:\ix"
>> If Not goFS.FolderExists(p) Then
>>    goFS.CreateFolder p
>> End If
>>
Error Number:       76
Error Description:  Path not found
```

I assume that your %1 argument holds a path that cannot be created because the prefix/parent path is invalid (no N: drive here). So (double) check the content of %1.

**Added on second thought:**

As you said:

> Now for some reason the UnZip method works perfectly fine for
>   downloading and unziping Ant, but for Tomcat it does not.

and wrote:

```
call :UnZipFile "%HOMEDRIVE\Apache\" "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.56.zip"
```

I further assume, that refering to HOMEDRIVE correctly - as in

```
call :UnZipFile "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\" "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.56.zip"
```

(mark the extra %), will solve your problem.

Comment: oh god... love them typos, was starring at the bloody thing for few hours and have not noticed that

Comment: @MaciejCygan, you should not have to stare at it for hours.  All you have to do is troubleshoot correctly. If you watch your script execute line by line you would have seen that the variable %homedrive% never expanded to its value. You even had a pause in your code right after that line.  It was staring right at you.

Comment: @Squashman yeah, but sometimes the easiest things are the hardest to find #